# The Fetch request does not return data

Tags: node.js, vue.js

A snippet of code on the app side. I can't figure out exactly where my mistake is. It is possible that the helper change leaves the method before it has time to wait for a response from the server

```
   Promise((resolve) => {     
                fetch('/currentDir1',{
                    method: 'POST',
                    mode: 'cors',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',                    
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(elem)                
                    })
                    .then(response => response.json())    
                    .then(json => this.helper = json)
                    .then(json =>  this.$emit("newvalue", json)) 
                    console.log("helper");
                    console.log(this.helper);
                    resolve("result");
             });
```

Server-side handler

```
router.post('/currentDir1',(req, res) =>{  
    console.log("POST");
    
    let body = "";   
    let pathToFile = "";
    req.on("data", function (data) {
        body += data;
    });
    req.on("end", function(currentData) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(body));
        currentData = JSON.parse(body);
        

        if(currentData.sizeOrType === "<папка>"){
            let dir = currentData.dir + currentData.fileName;
            // dir = "C:\\totalcmd";
            console.log(dir);                
            if(currentData.whichScreen){
                foo(dir, './data/firstScreen.json');
                pathToFile = './data/firstScreen.json';
                res.sendFile(path.resolve('./data/firstScreen.json'));
            }else{
                console.log('aaaa');
                Foo(dir, './data/secondScreen.json');
                pathToFile = './data/firstScreen.json';
                res.sendFile(path.resolve('./data/secondScreen.json'));
                
            }        
        }
        // res.json({ message: 'goodbye'})   
        res.json(path.resolve(pathToFile));     
    });        
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(pathToFile));
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure about the scope of this.helper? Try putting "this" into a variable outside the method to ensure the scope? i.e.

```
var that = this; 
Promise((resolve) => {     
                fetch('/currentDir1',{
                    method: 'POST',
                    mode: 'cors',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',                    
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(elem)                
                    })
                    .then(response => response.json())    
                    .then(json => that.helper = json)
                    .then(json =>  that.$emit("newvalue", json)) 
                    console.log("helper");
                    console.log(that.helper);
                    resolve("result");
             });
```